# Can we create tables with borders dynamically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

Iam trying to create a table with borders using TableLayout. If I add static rows in xml file i am able to see the borders. But the problem arises if I try to add some dynamic rows. Data for the table comes dynamically. Can anyone help in solving this problem. If possible please provide the source code(.java file and .xml file).

Comment: Did you check this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4156869/android-dynamic-table-layout-adding-views-throws-exception-illegalstateexceptio/4157298#4157298

Comment: @peter I may have missed, but that link explains how to add rows, not how to add borders to the rows.

Comment: @Ooops my bad, fastReading@work != goodIdea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a rectangle image to use as a background for the row. `TableRow` extends `View`, so this should work (untested).

```
TableRow row = new TableRow (this);
row.setBackgroundResource (android.R.drawable.edit_text);
// rest of your code
```

If it doesn't work, the (tested) solution is to add a color background to the table and padding to the row.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Aleadam. Your solution worked like magic for me. I tried out various complex things to get the border for the table which is created dynamically. But Your solution was simply awesome sir. I don't know how could I miss such a simple option. And I have one more doubt regarding that. If I have texts of different sizes to be added in a single row. Can I wrap the text to the width of the text view. If possible please provide me the solution.

Comment: @Krishna I'm glad it worked for you! I'm not sure I understand what you mean in the comment, but it seems that it would belong to a separate question. Can you create a new one and explain a little bit more what you need?